# How to divide 18 people into teams of 3 many times without having people interact more than once?

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say we have 18 people in a pool and want to divide them into teams of 3. After a round we want to make new teams where nobody has played together before (We don't have to care about opponents). How many times is it possible to create new teams of 3 without repeating interactions and how would such a formula look?

The only plan I have now is to try and brute force it but it would be fun to know how it's supposed to actually be solved.

Comment: @Adam no it is not.  Actually related concepts: [Steiner Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system) and specifically Steiner Triple Systems.  Also [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).  Unfortunately, $18$ is not of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+3$ so we will not have perfect symmetry here, we won't have everyone paired with each other person the same number of times.

Comment: @JMoravitz fair enough.

Comment: Better yet, [Social Golfer Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem).   See pages dedicated to providing arrangements [such as this one](https://goodenoughgolfers.com/).

Comment: This is great information, thanks!

Comment: Your question is a special case of [this question](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=19&k=3&t=2), and my answer there gives you all you need. In particular, to find the optimal way for 18 people, you take a Steiner triple system on the set {1, 2, … 18, 19}, and ignore all triples containing 19. [Here is an STS(19), from the La Jolla covering repository](https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=19&k=3&t=2).